# Magickick.NET-Q8-x64 version 7.2.4.0 mismatch between processor project being built "MSIL" and processor reference Magick.NET-Q8-x64.dl, AMD64

Tags: imagemagick, magick.net

I create a windows .net core 3.1 application in Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows 10 machine.
The project was set to Debug Any CPU.
I installed Magick.NET-Q8-x64 version 7.2.4.0 via a nuget package.
When I compiles the application Visual Studio's output window displayed this warning:
WHY does installing this package give this warning?
Is there a different Magick.Net nuget package I need to use

warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Users\Owner.nuget\packages\magick.net-q8-x64\7.24.0\lib\netstandard20\Magick.NET-Q8-x64.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
1>MajickWpfAppCore -> G:\code\Mark Logic\Magick.NET-main\MajickWpfAppCore\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MajickWpfAppCore.dll